# Prove Some questions with mathematical induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have some question and I want to prove them with mathematical induction.

1) $|\sin(nx)| \le n|\sin(x)|$

2) $\sqrt[n]{n!} \ge \sqrt{n}$

3) $1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1) \le n^n$

I use this method for question one but can you find easier way?
$P(0) = |\sin(0)| \le 0*|\sin(x)|$ It's true.

$P(n) = |\sin(nx)| \le n|\sin(x)|$

$P(n+1) = |\sin(nx + x)| \le (n+1)|\sin(x)|$

$\sin(nx + x)| = |\sin(nx)\cos(x) + \cos(nx)sin(x)|$

$|\sin(nx)\cos(x) + \cos(nx)sin(x)| \le |\sin(nx)\cos(x)| + |\cos(nx)sin(x)|$

$|\sin(nx)\cos(x)| + |\cos(nx)sin(x)| \le |n\sin(x)\cos(x)| + |\cos(nx)sin(x)|$ (we use p(n) for this)

$|n\sin(x)\cos(x)| + |\cos(nx)sin(x)| = |\sin(x)|(n|\cos(x)| + |\cos(nx)|)$

now, we must prove that:

$|\sin(x)|(n|\cos(x)| + |\cos(nx)|) \le (n+1)|\sin(x)| $ or same meaning

$(n|\cos(x)| + |\cos(nx)| \le n+1$

It's obvious because of domain of cos(x).

Is it possible to help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Is this homework? Regardless this certainly isn't linear algebra.

Comment: With mathematical induction there is two major steps.  You first have to prove your base step and then your inductive step.  So the first thing you have to think about is proving it for the case n=0 and then creating a proof that shows the n+1 case is true assuming the n case is true.

Comment: I check them for values 0, 1. They are true.

Comment: @AminBorjian when you are writing out your inductive proof you are expected to show that you have checked it for your base case (normally your base case is n=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINTS:**

**HINT (i)**: Using the triangle inequality, we have

$$\begin{align}
|\sin((n+1)x)|&=|\sin(nx)\cos(x)+\cos(nx)\sin(x)|\\\\
&\le |\sin(nx)|+|\sin(x)| \tag 1
\end{align}$$

---

**HINT (ii)**:  The inequality is equivalent to showing

$$n!\ge n^{n/2}$$

Then, note that

$$\begin{align}
(n+1)^{(n+1)/2}&=n^{n/2}(n+1)^{1/2}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n/2}\\\\
&\le n!(n+1)^{1/2}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n/2} \,\,\cdots \text{by the induction hypothesis} \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Use the fact that $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n/2}= \sqrt{2}$ for $n=1$ and $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n/2}\le e^{1/2}<\sqrt{3}$ for all $n$.

---

**HINT (iii)**:  Write $(2n-1)!!=\frac{(2n)!!}{2^n\,n!}$.  Then, the inequality is equivalent to showing

$$(2n)!!\le (2n)^n\,n!$$

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
(2n+2)!!&=2(n+1)(2n)!!\\\\
&\le 2(n+1)(2n)^n\,n!\,\,\cdots \text{by the induction hypothesis} \tag 3
\end{align}$$

---

**SPOILER ALERT:**  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solutions.

> From $(1)$ and the induction hypothesis $|\sin(nx)|\le n|\sin(x)|$, we see that $$\begin{align}|\sin((n+1)x)|&\le n|\sin(x)|+|\sin(x)|\\\\&=(n+1)|\sin(x)|\end{align}$$And we are done! From $(2)$, we have $$\begin{align}(n+1)^{(n+1)/2}&\le (n+1)!\,\frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n/2}}{(n+1)^{1/2}}\\\\&\le (n+1)!\end{align}$$since for $n=1$, $\frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n/2}}{(n+1)^{1/2}}=1$ and for $n\ge 2$, $\frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n/2}}{(n+1)^{1/2}}\le \sqrt{e/(n+1)}<1$.  And we are done!  From $(3)$, we see that $$\begin{align}(2n+2)!!&\le  2(n+1)(2n)^n\,n!\\\\&=(2n+2)^{n+1}(n+1)!\left(\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\right)\\\\&<(2n+2)^{n+1}(n+1)!\end{align}$$And we are done!

Comment: I solved two of questions. can you help me for meaning of **$!!$** in question 3? I search but I didn't find anything.

Comment: @AminBorjian Amin, I am happy to help.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark